# Editing code in question

Tags: discussion

I frequently answer questions on the `python` tag and one thing that happens (all the time) is that code is not correctly indented.  In python, the indenting of code blocks matters:

```
if foo:
bar()
elif other_foo:
other_bar()
```

is a `SyntaxError`.  In this case, it is completely obvious that the user meant to do:

```
if foo:
   bar()
elif other_foo:
   other_bar()
```

The question isn't about getting a `SyntaxError`, it's about something else, so it's pretty clear that this is just a copy/paste problem and not knowing how to clearly format code on SO.  Here's the question -- with the plethora of statements here on Meta about **NEVER EDIT CODE IN A QUESTION**, does that apply to this as well?  To fix it, *I would do nothing other than format the code so that it produces the behavior that is mentioned in the rest of the question*.

Of course, indenting of code is just an example.  mis-spelled variable names are another thing which I see occasionally.

My current policy is to leave a comment asking the OP to fix the problem.  Is that the correct way to go about this, or should I edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I routinely edit code for appearance only. By that I mean I won't change formatting that the user *intended* to have, but I will often edit a question to fix markdown problems. For example, if a "#" appears at the beginning of a line and gets turned into a headline, I'll fix that. Or if extra blank lines break a code sample up, or one line isn't indented enough and breaks a sample up, I'll fix those.

I think syntactically significant whitespace as in Python *could* fall under this category, but be careful. Sometimes a user's bad formatting could actually be causing the code to be misinterpreted, and you wouldn't want to accidentally change the meaning of the code.

Comment: Yeah, one ambiguity here is that you can't always tell when the block of code actually should end.  (sometimes it's obvious -- other times it isn't).  I wouldn't touch something if it isn't obvious.

Comment: In this (unusual) case, I'd say it's ok to edit the code if it makes the code consistent with the OP's description of the symptom.